# Chart.js com Angular usando o ng-include. Gráficos não aparecem

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chartjs

Olá.

No meu index.html tenho isto

```
    <div ng-include="'graficos.html'">
        </div>
```

no graficost.html tenho isto:

```
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_panel">
              <div class="x_title">
                <h2>Line graph<small>Sessions</small></h2>
                <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                  <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="x_content">
                <canvas id="lineChart"></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

no body do index.html declaro o chart.js e o grafico.js (onde crio os graficos) assim:

```
  <script src="../vendors/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script src="graficos.js"></script>
```

quando chamo a index.html, renderiza a página graficos.html chamada pelo ng-include mas me aparece este erro no console do Chrome:

> Chart.min.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Por isso não mostra os graficos que estão no graficos.js

Comment: Verifique como está o escopo na sua aplicação.
Como você está injetando o controller? Ng-Controller ou pelas Rotas?

Qual é o código que trabalha com seu canvas?

Comment: Acredito que não é um problema no controller, pois a página graficos.html que estou chamando no ng-include, é exibida, porem os gráficos feitos em JS, não.

Comment: A falta dele vai fazer com que os dados não sejam passados. Ele incluiu com ng-include porque achou o arquivo no caminho informado.

Comment: Verdade... coloquei o ng-controller na pagina que veio por include e fiz o module e controller no grafico.js.. Obrigado!

Comment: Ok, vou colocar como resposta aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique como está o escopo na sua aplicação.
Veja onde o controller está injetado, se não estiver injetado corretamente o canvas não vai buscar os dados.

Use ng-controller dentro do ng-include ou mesmo dentro do arquivo incluído ou use as rotas para injetá-lo.